# Having issues setting up smtp using codeigniter and office365

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, office365

I use Codeigniter for my development platform and php.

I can connect to an office365 mail server via Codeigniter's mail function using smtp.
I use an account email address and username to connect.
To make this work I need to put the account name in the from address otherwise the email fails.
Apparently as far as I can tell this is how office365 mail servers work when sending web form data from your website domain.
I have been told by an IT company that this will cause issues with the SPF record.
Just to add to it the company whos website it is wants to have the senders email address in the from part of the email address.
The other reason why I have to use an authenticated mail account is that if I don't, emails are sent to the junk folder, ie if i switch to 'mail' then they go straight to spam/junk folder.

What do i need to do to make the following work:

Send email so that it lands in their inbox instead of spam/junk folder from the website forms.
Use the senders email address in the from field of the email.

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: If the _sender's_ email also uses office365, you are done. Another option is to use a mail service, say sendgrid or mailchimp

Comment: Have a read up on DKIM and SPF as a good starting point. 
Sending email as if it comes from the 'senders email address' will trigger most spam filters - as the actual senders email will have protections in place. 

SendGrid, MailGun or PostMark offer cost effective solutions. Otherwise you need to look at optimising your server to have a valid from address, DKIM and SPF in place. And hope the IP address you're sending from has a good reputation and isn't blacklisted.

Comment: @nice_dev the senders email is scripted and at the moment is the same as the office365 account that the smtp config is using. This has to be the same in order for it to send to the authenticated mailbox, i dont really understand your comment "If the sender's email also uses office365" as i plug in the account email address into the code which is the mailbox account address that the email is being sent to, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Also, if i say I didnt use smtp and an authenticated mailbox, but wanted to send form data to a certain business email address on an office 365 server how can i achieve this without coming up with the same problems. Surely, if i used the business address in the from field it would be pushed straight to spam due to the restriction around that email address.